# Hibernate parent-child not saving foreign-key in table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities having parent child relationship - Person and Address.

They have a one-to-one relationship.

I am able to cascade save both of them by one save.

But the below code does not add a foreign_key address_id to Person table.

SQL:

```
create table PERSON (
   id number(20) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
alter table Person add  address_id number(20);
alter table Person add  CONSTRAINT FK_Address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (id);

create table Address (
   id number(20) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Hibernate code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="SOME_SEQ", sequenceName="pk_sequence")
public class Person 
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SOME_SEQ")
   private int id;

   @OneToOne
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
   private Address address;
}


@Entity
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="SOME_SEQ", sequenceName="pk_sequence")
public class Address 
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SOME_SEQ")
   private int id;

   @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   private Person person;
}
```

Driving code:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Person p = new Person();
Address add = new Address ();
p.setAddress(add);
add.setPerson(p);
id = (Integer) session.save(p); 
tx.commit();
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create the fk before the address table exists.  Where does the sql come from?

Comment: The SQL is created by me to create the tables necessary for put/get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. You have a column in Person that is a foreign key to the address table. But you map the association with [`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html), which means: The ID of this entity is also a foreign key to the address table. Use `@JoinColumn`. Not `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.